# Windows 7 User profiles issue - Shows logging off after entering corrupt password

Tags: windows-7, login, user-profiles

This issue has become specific as fixing one problem led to the other:

1) I deleted ntuser.* files while working in linux as they had ugly looking file extensions and I thought they are temporary files.

2) I started getting the message "The Group Policy Client service failed the logon. Access denied". This was the only user profile on my windows part.

I started looking on the Internet for solutions. I stumbled upon a solution to remove the sid field from the Registry ENtry "HLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

3) After this, when I login to the profile it shows "logging off" screen instantaneously.

My Present situation:

1) I can logon to this profile in Safe Mode.

2) I can make a new user profile and login to that profile in normal mode(Non safe mode).

However, I get old and trivial user settings and my stored passwords are gone.

I desperately want to revive my earlier User Profile.
Please give some suggestion based on my situation.

Comment: May be you can run a [system restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore)

Comment: Your stored passwords were in the NTUSER.DAT file that you deleted. That's half of the user portion of a user profile's registry. The other half has the user class portion.

Comment: @bobodes I already have done it several times using windows 7 integrated tool and with one that came with HP tools.

Comment: @Twisty Any pointers on how to get them back?

Comment: At this point you're looking at restoring from backup or doing data recovery.

Comment: Interesting. Seems 3 of my machines had this same issue today. I can log in but others cannot and the same message. Seems my computers love me